# Seeking a compact format for HTML ebooks for offline reading under Linux

Tags: html, linux, compression

I have a netbook running Linux and a large collection of computer books and reference material as HTML. I'd like some compact way of storing these books which can be browed without unpacking them first. This would save space and reduce wear on my small SSD.

If there was some way to convince Firefox to browse files contained in ZIP file, this would be ideal. (I know iCab (Mac) had a web archive format that worked this way.)  Perhaps a Firefox plugin? A small web server that can serve directly from ZIP files? Some magic FUSE module? Does anyone have any ideas?

On my PDA (which the netbook is largely replacing) I used iSilo for this, but it's not available for Linux, its conversions are lossy and it costs money.

Answer (score 1):

There is the FUSE zip thing here :
http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/

Gvfs should also support zip files.

Answer (score 0):

[Calibre](http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net) might help (convert to a compressed format, manage, view e-books).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) to open the html pages, and then save them as OO documents. OO documents are essentially a zip files.

Another option is to use OO to save as pdf.

You can even do this from a command line using this [OO macro](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=62219#62219).

Same with [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/) - you can use it on [commandline to convert](http://opensource.weblogsinc.com/2005/06/29/use-abiword-to-convert-filetypes-on-the-command-line/).

In the AbiWord example there is shown how to convert all files in a directory to a desired format (pdf). Then you can use [pdftools](http://www.sheelapps.com/index.php?p=PDFTools.HomePage) to merge all pages in one document.

Also, I do not know what windows manager your laptop has, but if it is KDE, konqueror (the file and web browser for KDE) opens web pages from inside a zip file w/o any problem.

Most probably Gnome's Nautilus can do this as well (I have no Gnome here to test).

Have you ever tried to open a zip file with whatever file manager you have, and then click on a web page inside it?

Comment: I would like to know why this was down-voted? Do not shy away, be a man, and tell.

Comment: Wasn't me, but here's a guess: the first half is not actually a usable solution to the question as posed. The second half is a good possibility though at least gnome browses by unpacking files individually. Can't follow links. CSS is broken.

Comment: I'm not sure for nautilus, but konqueror is a browser itself, so it just reads the page from the zip, if does not "unpack" individual file to feed to another browser. I'l extend the first part to a usable solution though.

Comment: Do you mean that the gnome solution can not use CSS? If so, still the first (convert to pdf) may work.

Comment: I'll give Konqueror a try and see if that helps. CSS: The solution should find the CSS, it doesn't work because gnome only unpacks the single entry opened from the zip file before handing it off to Firefox. Firefox then can't find the CSS because it hasn't been unpacked.